# Why is my bootstrap carousel item disappearing before completing the slide animation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, carousel

I have a carousel within a modal that every time you navigate to the next item the previous one begins to slide off the screen and just disappears before completing the animation. I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.2. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code or create a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this might be a problem if you are missing any closing tag of the div, that contains your carousel item.

If you miss the end tag then the sliding will occur only once i mean after the complition of one round the sliding will not reoccur. So check for this.

Here is a total example on [carousel image slider in Bootstrap 3](http://www.tapankumar.in/2014/01/carousel-image-slider-in-twiter-bootstrap.html) check it.

Comment: Thanks, my div closed in a wrong place. Put it a bit up and everything worked!